# How to handle utf characters in perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am  fetching a data base table field  value in Perl (which is 'utf8_unicode_ci') and trying to insert that value into another table  (which is also 'utf8_unicode_ci');

But I don't getting the value properly in perl.

The value I am trying to read and insert is `₨`.

I tried different solutions, but they didn't work

Can any one help?

I have tried the following code:

```
use Encode; $message = decode_utf8( $message );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may need to add this to the connection:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);
$dbh->do("SET NAMES 'utf8'");  #<-- add this after the connection was established
```

With `SET NAMES 'utf8'` we are doing in one sentence:

```
SET character_set_client = 'UTF8';
SET character_set_results = 'UTF8';
SET character_set_connection = 'UTF8';
```

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But what is 'NAMES' ?

Comment: Only one table field is set as 'utf8_unicode_ci'.
So if we do like that will it effect all data?

Comment: can we have a solution so that , only the required field will keep in utf8

Comment: ,the solution that You suggested is worked for me .
But let me know ,can we limit it for the particular field only? or will make issue on other fields which are in other character set

Comment: Use the CONVERT function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/charset-convert.html

Comment: Ok, iam giving correct answer for your answer.And now i just doing $dbh->do("SET NAMES 'utf8'");Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `mysql_enable_utf8` attribute when connecting to the database, then [DBD::mysql](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3amysql) will do the conversion for you.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:database=$db", $user, $pass",
                       { mysql_enable_utf8 => 1 });
```